# Running PHP script using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this script using the code

```
subprocess.call(["php  C:\Python27\a.php"])
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

i have tried changing path but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: I mean, presumably change the path to one that actually has a file?

Comment: that is the file path.Can I use something else

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(["php",  "C:\\Python27\\a.php"])
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> *args* is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either *shell* must be `True` (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

Also note that in python, like many other languages, the backslash in a normal string has [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings). You'll have to use double backslashes or a raw string to get the behavior you want.

Comment: maybe also specify php's path: `/usr/bin/php`

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
subprocess.call(["php",  "C:\\Python27\\a.php"])
```

or

```
subprocess.call(["php",  r"C:\Python27\a.php"])
```

should work.

Comment: can you give me the whole program.